# use a single return from a sql query

Tags: mysql

I'm using PHP to make a very specific sql query.  For example sake, I have the user's ID number, but I need their name.  So I do a sql query from that table with the ID number in order to return the name.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE userID=$thisuserid",$db);
```

Now I want to use that.  What's the most succinct way to go about making that result into a variable ths I can use?

edit:
I'm hoping that this is not the answer:

```
$rowCheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rowCheck > '0') {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach ($row as $val){
        $username = $val;
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used something like this to keep it short in the past:

```
list($name) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE userID=$thisuserid",$db));
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use MySQLi as bellow:

```
$db = new MySQLi($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$query = $db->query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE userID='.$thisuserid);
$result = $query->fetch_object();
echo $result->name;
```

If you use `SELECT *` so you also can access via $result->{field_name}

Comment: @Julian-Bayardo-Spadafora: Edited. Forget single quote

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to fetch any SQL result is through [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). To use it, you would do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE userID=$thisuserid",$db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name']; // You get an array with each column returned from your query.
}
```

Still, MySQL extension has been [replaced for MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), which is acknowledged to be faster and more practical. It has both OOP and structural bindings, and takes more into account your server settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE userID=$thisuserid",$db);

if (!$result) {
  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}
$name = mysql_fetch_row($result)[0];
```